# How to exclude files from outside my workspace from ESLint in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint

When I'm in a workspace and open an external file (from outside of workspace) in VSCode, how can I exclude this file from lint? More specifically from `pug-lint` but the same applies to `ESLint`?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for
[pug-lint](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-lint)
lists the option of
[excludeFiles](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-lint#excludefiles)
as follows:

> **excludeFiles**
>
> Type: Array
>
> Default: ["node_modules/**"]
>
> Disables style checking for specified paths declared with glob
>   patterns.

From examining the
[source-code of pug-lint](https://npmtest.github.io/node-npmtest-pug-lint/build/coverage.html/node-npmtest-pug-lint/node_modules/pug-lint/lib/linter.js.html),
it seems that these options are specified in a `.js` file in the `rules`
sub-folder, or specified in the
[Configuration file](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-lint#configuration-file).

Comment: The thing is that I want to exclude all files from outside my project (workspace), as in: if ./ is my project root folder, I want to exclude everything out of this (.././). This happens if I'm working in a project and open some file from outside that project, and ESLint starts working on it and messaging me about lint errors...

Comment: The developers didn't think about this possibility - you will have to write rules for `excludeFiles` that cover your main outside-project folders.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear for me how could I do that?

Comment: I suppose add a JavaScript file under the `rules` subfolder of pug-lint that contains something like `{ "excludeFiles": [array of paths]  }`. As I'm not using pug-lint, that's as far as I can go.